# Trouble proving trigonometric inequality related to induction (?)

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, induction

The question is as follows:

Prove that, if $\theta=\cot^{-1}x, (0<\theta<\pi)$ then
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^n\theta}{\mathrm{d}x^n}=(-1)^n(n-1)!\sin^n{\theta}\sin{n\theta},$$

where $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Show that the absolute value of $\displaystyle{\frac{\mathrm{d}^n\theta}{\mathrm{d}x^n}}$ never exceeds $(n-1)!$ if $n$ is odd, or $\displaystyle{(n-1)!\cos^{n+1}\left(\frac{\pi}{2n+2}\right)}$ if $n$ is even.

My attempt at a solution:

The first part is a relatively straight forward induction proof that I managed to prove easily, but for the second part, I have honestly no idea on how to structure the proof.

I know that
$$\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}^n\theta}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\right|=|(-1)^n(n-1)!\sin^n{\theta}\sin{n\theta}|=(n-1)!|\sin^n{\theta}\sin{n\theta}|\leqslant(n-1)!$$

due to both $|\sin\theta|\leqslant 1$ and $|\sin{n\theta}|\leqslant 1$, but how does $n$ being even or odd affect the upper bound of $\displaystyle{\frac{\mathrm{d}^n\theta}{\mathrm{d}x^n}}$?

Comment: $(n-1)!\cos^{n+1}(\frac{\pi}{2n+2}) < (n-1)!$

Comment: @SenZen but what is the relevance of $n$ being even?

Comment: The alleged upper bound  for $n=2$ is $\cos^3(\pi/6)=1/8$ but $\sin^2(\pi/3)\sin(2\pi/3)=3\sqrt{3}/8$. So it isn't even true.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales $\cos^3 (\pi/6) = (\sqrt3/2)^3 = 3\sqrt3/8$

Comment: @Daryl Hong no idea lol

Comment: @player3236 Thanks, proves once again that I should not do this at 2 AM.